# Combine Swashbuckle custom tag and description

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

My requirements:

- I want actions tagged by the lowercase controller name (rather than pascal case), so I changed that using `c.TagActionsBy(...)`
- I want a description per tag, so I added this to each controller:  `[SwaggerTag("Foo")]`.

But when using both these changes, there is a conflict/bug in the UI:

- the new lowercase tags are shown as expected, but no description
- the old pascal case tags are also shown, with descriptions

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What version of swashbuckle are you using?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Latest: `4.0.1`

Comment: Strange I do not see any potential conflict between the two:
- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/search?q=TagsSelector
- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/search?q=SwaggerTagAttribute

Comment: Do you have a sample project reproducing your issue?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Sorry no. Actually [there is a conflict](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#add-tag-metadata) but no solution or workaround for it. So I posted here.

Comment: I think this might be possible with an iDocumentFilter... Do you have a sample project?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Sorry no I don't have a demo, it's a known bug/limitation. Maybe someone had the same problem and will post a solution here.